# Why does my span element look so bad in IE9?

Tags: html, css

I have a orange today span tag that looks fine in other browsers, even IE8! But in IE9 it looks terrible (expands the entire page and causes other elements to not be structured correctly).  I tried changing the element to a div, changed it to inline-block, added a width, and played around with the vertical align but I can't figure out what it doesnt like about it. If you take the today span tag out everything pops back into place.

http://auroriella.com/test/ui_candidate_test.html

```
.today {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fba435;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd; 
    border-right: 1px solid #fba435;    
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You say it looks okay in IE8, but I'm mot sure how you got `hsl()` colours working in IE8 -- it doesn't support them at all.

Comment: @JacquesGoulet - look at the edit history. It was all hsl when the question was first asked.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest specifying width for .dayContainer instead of (or together with) .day.current.

On the page from the post, this will be ok:

```
.dayContainer{
    ...
    width: 148px;
    ...
}
```